# Audio is not playing on iphone (react 360)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, web-audio-api, virtual-reality, react-360

I am working very hard to get audio to play on my mobile phone with react 360. Through reading various documentation, I've learned that in order to play audio on mobile, I need to enact an html entity to create a user interaction. Once a user interacts by clicking the button, audio should be able to play on mobile. This does not seem to be the case.

In my `index.html` file I have the following code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ExampleVR</title>
    <style>body { margin: 0; }</style>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Attachment point for your app -->

    <div id="container">


      <button id="enter" onclick="enterApp();">
        Click to Enter VR
      </button>


    </div>
    <script src="./client.bundle?platform=vr"></script>
    <script>
      // Initialize the React 360 application


      function enterApp() {
        React360.init(
          'index.bundle?platform=vr&dev=true',
          document.getElementById('container'),
          {
            assetRoot: 'static_assets/',
          }
        );  
      }


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I have created am html button that when clicked, loads my React 360 code . However, when I click a `VrButton` in mobile, it still does not play. I've followed the recommendations as documented and it works on all browsers on desktop with the exception of mobile. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: I know nothing about how React360 plays audio but I assume it uses Web Audio API. Judging from the code you posted it might not work because it somehow asynchronously initiates audio playback which does not fulfill the requirement of "activated from user action". You can learn more about unlocking Web Audio here: https://paulbakaus.com/tutorials/html5/web-audio-on-ios/

Comment: One more thing: did you check the mute switch on your iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was the solution to fix the audio issue:

https://github.com/facebook/react-360/issues/652